# Issues with scroll to top when constantly updating cell size

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView with automatic sizing cells. The contents of each cell revolve around the counting of time, so the size of the cell could change every second. I am currently using a timer scheduled every 1 second to tell the table view to update the cell sizes:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(timeUpdateNotification), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

@objc func timeUpdateNotification() {
    // ... cells get notified to update contents here ...

    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

This works fairly well but has issues when the user taps to scroll to the top of the list. The animation is a bit janky and often times doesn't make it to the top. Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Why don't you considering disabling animation during scroll?

Comment: I'm not sure that would help. Scrolling or hitting the status bar to go to top could happen after the tableView updates have started but before they have completed

Comment: Why do u need to update cell sizes manually? After you changed content of cells in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, `UITableView` will resolve cell sizes by calling `heightForRowAtIndexPath` or automatically if u are using `AutoLayout` and `estimatedRowHeight`

Comment: cellForRow is only called on initial layout, subsequent text changes won't trigger it and therefore don't update the size

Comment: can you provide code that you are using for a scroll to the top of the list?

Comment: Didn't write any code, just using the built into iOS "scroll to top"

Comment: Generally I would consider it a better structure, if the cell updates are only triggered by changes of the data (counting of time?). And not by a (separat?) timer. Seems just a bit hacky and error prone to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set a flag when the table is scrolling you can detect it in your timer function and not update while it is set. `UITableView` is a descendant of `UIScrollView`, so you can use some of the scroll view delegates to do this. If you override `scrollViewShouldScrollToTop()` and `scrollViewDidScrollToTop()` you will know when the scroll view is scrolling to the top and when it has finished.

```
override func scrollViewShouldScrollToTop(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) -> Bool {
    NSLog("scrollViewShouldScrollToTop")
    isScrolling = true
    return true
}

override func scrollViewDidScrollToTop(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    NSLog("scrollViewDidScrollToTop")
    isScrolling = false
}
```

You could also extend this to detect when the user is dragging/scrolling the view, to prevent the timer function from updating at these occasions too.

```
override func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    NSLog("scrollViewWillBeginDragging")
    isScrolling = true
}

override func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    if (!decelerate) {
        // Only catch if scrolling stopped
        NSLog("scrollViewDidEndDragging")
        isScrolling = false
    }
}
override func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    NSLog("scrollViewDidEndDecelerating")
    isScrolling = false
}
```

I have added some logging to the functions, so that you can see what is going on. You can remove these, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Invalidate the timer when they click to scroll to top, then as soon as it reaches top start it again.

Edit: That way, it won't update content which may move content higher without updating the "top" of the table view.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
I solved it with the help of a manual height calculation for each cell.

```
var cellHeights: [Int: CGFloat] = [:]
```

In the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, calculate the height:

```
cellHeights[byRow] = cell.getCellHeight()
```

In the cell itself

```
func getCellHeight() -> CGFloat {

    let userInfoHeight: CGFloat = userInfoHeightConstraint.constant
    let actionHeight: CGFloat = actionViewHeightConstraint.constant
    let descriptionBottom: CGFloat = descriptionBottomConstraint.constant

    let descriptionWidth = self.frame.width - leftAvatarConstraint.constant - descriptionRightConstraint.constant
    let descriptionHeight: CGFloat = descriptionLabel.textHeight(width: descriptionWidth)

    let height = userInfoHeight + actionHeight + descriptionBottom + descriptionHeight

    return height
}

extension UILabel {
func textHeight(width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {

    var textHeight: CGFloat = 0

    if let text = self.text {

        let customLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude))
        customLabel.numberOfLines = self.numberOfLines
        customLabel.text = text
        customLabel.font = self.font
        customLabel.sizeToFit()

        textHeight = customLabel.frame.height
    }

    return textHeight
}}
```

I'm using UITableViewAutomaticDimension.
I additionally have the functionality to change the size of the cell at various clicked on it.

Therefore, in my task, this works fine:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return presenter.cellHeights[indexPath.row] ?? 0
}
```

But I think that you can immediately set the height:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return presenter.cellHeights[indexPath.row] ?? 0
}
```